# Example of non-computable implicit operations

Tags: profinite-groups

I used notation of paper of Jorge Almeida "*Dynamics of implicit operations and tameness of pseudovarities of group*" in my question.

> Let $V$ be a pseudovarity of finite groups. We know that every element $\pi$ of a $A$-generated free pro-$V$ group can be viewed as a implicit operation.

I want an example of non-computable implicit operation.

Comment: Could you define your terms to make this question more accessible?

Comment: A trivial example in two generators is $\prod x^{n!}y^{a_nn!}$ where $a_n\ge 1$ is any increasing non-computable sequence of positive integers.

Comment: @Ycor could you please tell me why this implicit operation is not computable? I have another example and I proved that that one is not computable. But I can not prove this one is not computable